# Re.sub() in Python does not accept a list as an input parameter

Tags: python, data-science, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean a dataset and while doing so I came across a column named "production_companies" with about a 1000 values. This column contains unnecessary symbols for example: The column values are like this `[{name: 'Pixar', id:"3}]`.
I wish to remove the unnecessary symbols like: " {} [] , the text values "name" and "id" as well as the integers.

```
list1=[]

list1= data.production_companies

for i in list1:

    re.sub('\d+','',list1)
```

The problem is that `re.sub` does not accept list as a parameter. It only accepts a string as an input parameter.
I need to use a list to store the `production_companies` values and iterate through it using a for loop because there are many values in the column and I need to remove the symbols and unnecessary text from all of them at once.

Can anyone please tell me what should I do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You better parse it with a JSON parser.

Comment: "columns"? Are you using a `pandas.DataFrame`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have imported the data from a csv file and the data is stored in the following format for the production_companies column in csv.:  [{name: 'Pixar', id:"3}]. I am totally new to python so I don't have an in-depth knowledge about the different ways in which this can be done

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list from an existing one.

```
list2 = [re.sub('\d+', '', item) for item in list1]
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will try doing that. But as far as I know re.sub() only accepts string as an input parameter. That's the error which I got

Comment: @Manila, you should really learn the basics of the Python programming language. Especially what a list comprehension is, and why it doesn't really make any sense for `re.sub` to take a list when list comprehension exist.